# disable sandbox tomcat 9 ubuntu 20.04

Tags: security, ubuntu, tomcat

I have a Tomcat 9 package of Ubuntu 20.04 installed.

Like in the manual here: https://salsa.debian.org/java-team/tomcat9/blob/master/debian/README.Debian

We need to set all the filesystems one by one (overriding).

--

Is there a way to disable the sandboxing or a way to include all filesystems or all the "/".

Or, is there a way to include a wildcard? Like all /home* (/home, /home02, /home03)

Answer (score 4):

This is controlled by systemd .
The systemd tomcat9 service file on ubuntu is:

```
/etc/systemd/system/multi-user.target.wants/tomcat9.service
```

To disable the filesystem protections you'll need to change the ProtectSystem directive from the default of 'strict' to 'false'.

```
ProtectSystem=false
```

After that run:

```
sudo systemctl daemon-reload
sudo service tomcat9 restart
```

Comment: Which part of the documentation allowed you to guess what the ProtectSystem property is used for?

Comment: To reply to my own comment, this is part of systemd.exec man page: " 'ProtectSystem=' Takes a boolean argument or the special values "full" or "strict". If true, mounts the /usr/ and the boot loader directories (/boot and /efi) read-only for processes invoked by this unit. If set to "full", the /etc/ directory is mounted read-only, too. If set to "strict" the entire file system hierarchy is mounted read-only, except for the API file system subtrees /dev/, /proc/ and /sys/"